# Restlet + Spring application: Tomcat server requires restart for different HTTP method to work successfully

Tags: spring-mvc, restlet

Here are the details of my application which is Spring Restlet integration implementation.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
  <display-name>My work</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Configuration Class for Rest:

```
package com.mycompany.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder;
import org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import com.mycompany.data.RegionDAO;
import com.mycompany.resource.RegionResource;
import com.mycompany.resource.RegionsResource;
import com.mycompany.service.RegionService;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Restlet root() {

        final SpringRouter router = new SpringRouter(this.restletContext());

        router.attach("/service/regions", new SpringFinder() {
            @Override
            public ServerResource create() {
                // lookup-method
                return AppConfig.this.regionsResource();
            }
        });

        router.attach("/service/regions/{regionid}", new SpringFinder() {
            @Override
            public ServerResource create() {
                // lookup-method
                return AppConfig.this.regionResource();
            }
        });

        return router;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public Context restletContext() {
        return new Context();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DataSource dataSource;

        dataSource = new org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "",
                "");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public RegionsResource regionsResource() {
        return new RegionsResource();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegionResource regionResource() {
        return new RegionResource();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegionService regionService() {
        return new RegionService();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegionDAO regionDao() {
        return new RegionDAO();
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.mycompany.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Controller
public class RestletController extends DispatcherServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private Restlet root;

    @Autowired
    private Context context;

    private ServletAdapter adapter;

    public RestletController() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public final void postConstruct() {
        final Application application = new Application(this.context);
        application.setInboundRoot(this.root);

        this.adapter = new ServletAdapter(this.getServletContext());
        this.adapter.setNext(application);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public final void request(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        this.adapter.service(request, response);
    }
}
```

Server Resource class:

```
package com.mycompany.resource;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.ext.json.JsonRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.mycompany.model.Region;
import com.mycompany.service.RegionService;

public class RegionsResource extends ServerResource {

    @Autowired
    private RegionService regionService;

    @Get
    public Representation doGet() {

        String errString = "";
        try {

            return this.toJSONArray(this.regionService.readAllRegions());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StringRepresentation(errString,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    }

    @Post("json")
    public Representation doPost(Representation entity) {
        String errString = "";

        try {
            JsonRepresentation represent = new JsonRepresentation(entity);
            JSONObject jsonobject = represent.getJsonObject();

            Region region = new Region();
            region.setRegId(jsonobject.getInt("regId"));
            region.setRegName(jsonobject.getString("regName"));

            this.regionService.createRegion(region);

            return new JsonRepresentation(region);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StringRepresentation(errString,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    }

    private Representation toJSONArray(final Collection<?> collection) {
        final JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
        for (final Object bean : collection) {
            result.put(new JSONObject(bean));
        }
        return new JsonRepresentation(result);
    }

}
```

I am running the application on Tomcat server in Eclipse IDE.

** To describe the what problem is, I will elaborate the test scenarios step-wise (I am using REST Client for testing):**

1. When I test HTTP GET, application works fine and *Representation doGet()* method of the Server Resource class gets called. But when I test HTTP POST,  the same *Representation doGet()* is getting called.
2. I restart the Tomcat server and test HTTP POST, this time application correctly calls *Representation doPost(Representation entity)* method of the Server Resource class . But when when I test HTTP GET,  the same *Representation doPost(Representation entity)* is getting called.

So, I notice that every time the execution is getting routed to the method corresponding to last HTTP method type call. 
With Tomcat server restart, the 1st Request is routed to correct method, but subsequent (different HTTP method) Request is not getting routed correctly.

Can you please help understand , why is the server restart needed? How to rectify?

I didn't face this problem when I had "org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet" (without Spring integration) based implementation.

Hope, I have provided all the details to explain the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've not taken time to understand clearly what happens.
But I just wonder why you systematically override the SpringFinder#create method. I would just use the provided constructor:

```
router.attach("/service/regions", new SpringFinder(getContect(), RegionsResource.class);
```

The finder is dedicated to instantiate the ServerResource for each incoming calls.

Comment: Hi Thierry, thanks for looking into it. **RegionsResource** has been defined as Spring @Bean. Without instantiating it, the dependencies of the **RegionsResource** (in this case "RegionService") wouldn't be injected and I get NullPointerException at line `this.regionService.readAllRegions()`. Do you suspect that this might be cause of the original issue?